# Azure Search CreateIndexAsync fails with CamelCase field names FieldBuilder

Tags: azure-search-.net-sdk

Azure Search V11 
I can't get this to work. But with the standard FieldBuilder the index is created.

```
private static async Task CreateIndexAsync(SearchIndexClient indexClient, string indexName, Type type)
{
    var builder = new FieldBuilder
    {
        Serializer = new JsonObjectSerializer(new JsonSerializerOptions {PropertyNamingPolicy = new CamelCaseNamingPolicy()})
    };
    var searchFields = builder.Build(type).ToArray();
    var definition = new SearchIndex(indexName, searchFields);

    await indexClient.CreateIndexAsync(definition);
}
```

`

```
public class CamelCaseNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
{
     public override string ConvertName(string name)
     {
         return char.ToLower(name[0]) + name.Substring(1);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See [our sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/search/Azure.Search.Documents/samples/Sample04_FieldBuilderIgnore.md#create-an-index) for `FieldBuilder`. Basically, you must use a naming policy for both `FieldBuilder` and the `SearchClient`:

```cs
var clientOptions = new SearchClientOptions
{
  Serializer = new JsonObjectSerializer(
    new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
      PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    }),
};

var builder = new FieldBuilder
{
  Serializer = clientOptions.Serializer,
};

var index = new SearchIndex("name")
{
  Fields = builder.Build(type),
};

var indexClient = new SearchIndexClient(uri, clientOptions);

await indexClient.CreateIndexAsync(index);
await Task.DelayAsync(5000); // can take a little while

var searchClient = new SearchClient(uri, clientOptions);
var response = await searchClient.SearchAsync("whatever");
```

While this sample works (our sample code comes from oft-executed tests), if you have further troubles, please be sure to post the exact exception message you are getting.